# Disabling a Win32 function at compile time

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

Dealing with a bizarre and irritating situation here...I'm using code from an open source project that has a function called DeleteFile(std::string filename).  However, if I call DeleteFile("const string") it dumps to the Win32 version instead.

Is there some way to selective disable specific Win32 functions during compile?  #pragma depreciated will WARN me, but what I really want is to utterly undeclare the Win32 version of DeleteFile at all in some header.

Comment: don't include windows.h or use #undef DeleteFile (at the right place)

Comment: DeleteFile is a macro (defined as either DeleteFileW or DeleteFileA) so, as suggested by @engf, if you #undef it after including the windows headers it should stop it interfering.

Comment: altternatively you could convert your "const string" to a std::string. Overload resolution should handle that just fine if the open source version is defined after include "windows.h"

Comment: Thanks engf-010, I had no idea it was just a macro!

Comment: @KiraHoneybee most Win32 functions that deal with strings are implemented as precompiler macros that map to corresponding `W` (Wide) or `A` (ANSI) functions depending on whether `UNICODE` is defined or not, respectively.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you aren't passing a `std::string` then? Something like `DeleteFile("const string"s)` [does that](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s).

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does the `DeleteFile()` function from your open-source library actually do?

Comment: @engf-010: The problem with "overload resolution" is that windows.h's macro could change your **call** to `DeleteFileA`, while the function is still defined as `DeleteFile` without the `A`. This will give a linker error. Microsoft really should have defined a `<windows.hpp>`. with a C++ namespace and C++ overloading.

Comment: @MSalters: yes ,that's why I appended the "if the open source is defined after include <Windows.h>". The function name will be macroed into DeleteFileX (A or W). What I suspect is already happening (I may be wrong of course).

Comment: @engf-010: I think you're mixing definition and declaration there. The `DeleteFile(std::string)` function is probably defined somewhere else entirely, in a Translation Unit that does not include `windows.h` at all. The declaration in the library's header and the later use in the OP's code are where the macro problem hits.

Comment: @MSalter: I really meant both and since it's an open source project I assumed that's the case. Technically you're 100% correct.